# Django Model Method Performance With self.image.width

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following Model method....

```
def make_image_width(self):
    """
    Returns image width of the object.
    """
    if self.image:
        return self.image.width
    return "null"
```

When I run this within a serializers it take 2 mins to render 100 objects.

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image_width = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='make_image_width')


    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (
            'id','image_width',)
```

**Why is `self.image.width` so slow? and how can I improve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method reads image file to get the width.

You should create an integer field in your model and point to it by using `width_field` attribute of the [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField).